# How to get a PySpark Dataframe containing al sundays between the current date and a given number of weeks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a constant integer `MAX_WEEKS`, I want to get all Sundays between today's date and today's date + `MAX_WEEKS` weeks.

For example, take today's date (`2023-04-17`) at the time of writing and `MAX_WEEKS` = 5. My desired output would be a PySpark Dataframe looking like this (where all entries can be of the Date Type):

```
Date
2023-04-23
2023-04-30
2023-05-07
2023-05-14
2023-05-21
```

I tried the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

current_date = f.current_date()
    number_of_weeks = 0
    dates = []
    while number_of_weeks <= MAX_WEEKS:
        next_date = f.next_day(current_date, "Sunday")
        dates.append(next_date)
        current_date = next_date
        number_of_weeks += 1
```

But that gives me an output like this:

```
[Column<'next_day(current_date(), Sunday)'>, Column<'next_day(next_day(current_date(), Sunday), Sunday)'>, Column<'next_day(next_day(next_day(current_date(), Sunday), Sunday), Sunday)'>, Column<'n....
```

I know the problem lies in the fact that the output of `f.current_date()` produces a DateType column, and that `f.next_day()` requires a column as input, but I can't figure out how to get this to work (or find examples that teach me how). Moreover, I think this solution looks way too ugly to be the most elegant and efficient one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using spark for this ? it will make it more complicated for you, try a python library, because spark functions typically return a column.

Comment: if you already have a list of Sundays (or can easily create one), you could just use the list to create a spark dataframe. full disclosure, there are other ways that can do the operations in spark dataframe, but the small magnitude of your problem does not make it a good fit for spark (IMO)